# How can I access my virtual environment created 1 week ago using ubuntu? I just know the name of the virtual environment but idk how access| PYTHON

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I installed my first virtual environment using this commands below

Commands used:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y python3-venv
mkdir awesome_python_project
cd awesome_python_project
python3 -m venv awesome_venv
source awesome_venv/bin/activate
```

but I can't access it again, does anyone knows why?

Comment: What's the message it give you after running the source command?- just nothing? Unrelated, but you should use `virtualenvwrapper` and then you can just do `workon awesome_venv` from anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-active your virtual environment again by going to the `awesome_python_project` folder and repeat the last command.

That is:

```
cd awesome_python_project
```

To go to the project folder. And

```
source awesome_venv/bin/activate
```

To activate your virtual environment